# Function overriding another function?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with my program, basically we have to make a robot bargain hunt as a project and add a individual feature at the end. My idea was to add an option to change the model of the ai (simple I know, but im still a rookie). The are 3 main files, one for main menu, one for sprite selection and one for actual game. I am using pygame, and the problem lies in the sprite selection GUI, where you can either press 1, 2 or 3 to load a model and start the game. The problem is that when pressing 1, 2 or 3 doesn't do anything.

```
class Environment():

    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = graphics.SCREEN
        self.gui_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        bckImg = pygame.image.load('map1.png') # loading an image of the map
        pygame.font.init()   # font initialisation
        myfont = pygame.font.Font('font1.ttf', 65)  # choosing the font
        myfont1 = pygame.font.Font('font1.ttf', 40)
        myfont2 = pygame.font.Font('font1.ttf', 30)
        myfont3 = pygame.font.Font('font1.ttf', 32)
        title = myfont.render("IT BELONGS IN THE MUSEUM !", 1, (0,0,0))
        startTheGame = myfont1.render("PRESS 'ENTER' TO START", 1, (0,200,0))
        closeTheMenu = myfont2.render("PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT", 1, (180,0,0))
        chooseTheSprite = myfont3.render("PRESS 'C' TO CHANGE THE AI MODEL", 1, (0,100,0))
        self.surface.blit(bckImg, (0,0))  #blitting the background
        self.surface.blit(title, (375,80)) #blitting the title
        self.surface.blit(startTheGame, ((500),700))
        self.surface.blit(closeTheMenu, ((635),885))
        self.surface.blit(chooseTheSprite, ((450,800)))


    def process_input(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # Menu control
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
                if (event.key == K_RETURN):
                    print("START GAME")
                    main.start()
                elif (event.key == K_c):
                    spriteGUI.SpriteGui()

                elif (event.key == K_q): # Quit game
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        pass

    def render(self):
        self.gui_group.draw(self.surface)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the main menu key events function

```
class SpriteGui():

    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = graphics.SCREEN
        self.gui_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        bckImg = pygame.image.load('map1.png') # loading an image of the map
        player1 = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
        player2 = pygame.image.load('player2.png')
        player3 = pygame.image.load('player3.png')
        pygame.font.init()   # font initialisation
        myfont = pygame.font.Font('font1.ttf', 65)  # choosing the font
        title = myfont.render("CHOOSE THE MODEL ", 1, (0,0,0))
        choosePlayer1 = myfont.render("[1]", 1, (0,51,0))
        choosePlayer2 = myfont.render("[2]", 1, (0,51,0))
        choosePlayer3 = myfont.render("[3]", 1, (0,51,0))
        self.surface.blit(bckImg, (0,0))  #blitting the background
        self.surface.blit(title, (375,80)) #blitting the title
        self.surface.blit(choosePlayer1, (315, 700))
        self.surface.blit(choosePlayer2, (745, 700))
        self.surface.blit(choosePlayer3,(1165, 700))
        self.surface.blit(player1, (270,400))
        self.surface.blit(player2, (700,400))
        self.surface.blit(player3, (1120, 400))


    def process_inputs(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # Menu control
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_1):
                    config.playerCh = 'player1.1.png'
                    print("Yo")
                elif (event.key == K_2):
                    config.playerCh = 'player2.1.png'
                    print("Yo2")
                elif (event.key == K_3):
                    config.playerCh = 'player3.1.png'
                    print("yo3")
                elif (event.key == K_q):
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        pass
    def render(self):
        self.gui_group.draw(self.surface)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

and this is the sprite selection key event function. 
Once I get to the sprite selection menu, the key events from the top function still work, but the ones from the 2nd function don't work for some reason. My idea was that the first function is somehow overriding the second one, but not sure how to fix that. Just to say these two functions are in two different classes in two separate files. I would really appreciate the help, and as I said before I am a rookie so my programming understanding is not the best.

Thank you

Comment: are you using `@...` decorators before these functions? And yes, creating two functions with the same name (outside a class) will cause an overwrite of the function name. just as `def sys(): pass` would cause you inable to do `import sys` because `sys` has been replaced.

Comment: No, I am not using decorators anywhere. (Didn't know what they were before looking them up >.<) Both of these functions are in two separate classes. If you want I can show the whole code.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to include a [gist](http://gist.github.com/) to the whole code, but perhaps mention in the question itself that it's two functions based in a class.

Comment: Edited the main post, these are the two main files.

Answer (score 1):

pygame.event.get() will *remove* all events from the event queue. This means that when you call it the first time, it removes those events and then you iterate over them. If the event type is not in your if/elif section it will skip it.

Subsequently, when you do the second call to pygame.event.get(), all the previous events (even if they were not acted upon) have already been removed, so, only new events that have happened since will be in the queue.

I would recommend using the optional parameter type or typelist to specify only the events you would like to parse at that time.

See: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get

Comment: So in my case what you mean to do is: for event in pygame.event.get(KEYDOWN) ?

Comment: @Dave I think what you should instead do is abstract the event handling to it's own class, and then create a function in both Environment and SpriteGUI called handle_event() which takes an Event. You could then create an array of these functions, and inside the EventHandler pass the event to each function.